# Why my data is too large relative at really size?

Tags: mysql

i have problem with my database, i collect dump to other database to analyze it and i have create table to reference date checked so when i see my interface phpmyadmin, i see my table size equal at 16Kio for two date with id !

i saw document here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html
and the date type size is 3 bytes ... the différence is too big, and i have problem with all data !
the size of original dump is 1.9Mo for one dump, in my database the size is 5Mo !

i don't know where does the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem,

The database in MySQL is not only data, you must consider space used by:

- Table definition
- Table indexed (>= table data)
- Table data

Each field type have different storage methods.

The dump file only contains table definitions and data as SQL inserts.

**Checking your db structure and sample dump:**

Your database are stored as `InnoDB` with `UTF8`, an your dumps are stored using `MyISAM` with `latin1`, is a big difference because UTF character sets use more space to store string/varchar data and InnoDB uses additional space because the table is stored physically inside InnoDB files.

I choose a dump file and one table then I create the same table using InnoDB with UTF8, see the **difference in sizes**:

```
mysql> call tools.sp_status(database());
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------------+
| Table Name          | Engine | Rows  | Size    | Collation         |
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------------+
| BDDJoueurs          | MyISAM | 33981 | 2.47 Mb | latin1_swedish_ci |
| BDDJoueurs_unicode  | InnoDB | 33981 | 6.03 Mb | utf8_unicode_ci   |
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------------+
```

I think you are using InnoDB to analyze, maybe is a good idea change your consolidated data to MyISAM preserving your character set.

Note: I use a custom [show table status](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/a-better-show-table-status/).

Comment: yes but there is a really problem i have one years of dump to analyze so 365 * 1.9Mo = 693Mo i know that other anyone use max 170Mo to analyze with my model 365 * 5Mo = 1 825Mo ! just impossible !

Comment: What is Mo? is a megabyte?

Comment: Mo = MB sorry... and my table Date have only an id type integer and date type date

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Eu8gnn5p my schema and the dump is here http://s1.fourmizzz.fr/BDDJoueur/ for my test i collect two dump total size in DB 10.3 MB !

Comment: I added new comments to my answer based on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Table size is not a simple multiple of the number of rows, more to do with the page size. 16KB sounds about right for a single page (see mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html)). Your two rows would take less than 1 page, so 1 page is sufficient.

There is other overhead too for indexes, metadata, etc.

BTW What is a `Mo`, a `Kio`?